# Can I get a fraction from a number in python?

Tags: python, fractions

I am doing some calculations and before outputting I want to change the number to a fraction.
For example 0.25 would become 1/4, well in a list of the two numbers [1, 4].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`fractions` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) to do that:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> fractions.Fraction(0.25)
Fraction(1, 4)
>>> f = fractions.Fraction(0.25)
>>> f.numerator
1
>>> f.denominator
4
```

For arbitrary floats as input, you really want to use the [`.limit_denominator()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) to limit your fractions to sane approximations of the floating point number:

```
>>> from math import pi, cos
>>> fractions.Fraction(cos(pi/3))
Fraction(4503599627370497, 9007199254740992)
>>> fractions.Fraction(cos(pi/3)).limit_denominator()
Fraction(1, 2)
```

Comment: I would use `.limit_denominator` to avoid weird output with e.g. `Fraction(0.1)`. Otherwise, this is an absolutely solid answer.

Comment: @nneonneo: Sure, and you should *always* study the documentation of any module you want to start using, not just take the answer example code for granted! :-)